# How to run NUnit test in MonoDevelop 2.2 in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nunit, monodevelop

I was following a tutorial but I can't find the option to run tests.

Comment: Which tutorial? What tests? Provide a bit more info... ;)

Comment: Probably this one http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-nunit-with-monodevelop/

Comment: @ROMANARMY this is one the tutorials I was following

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK Debian/Ubuntu puts the NUnit addin in a separate package called something like "monodevelop-nunit".